# Flutter Slider not updating when slided through

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]Here I'm trying to show a dialog when tapped on 'Set Discount Percentage'.
But the problem is that the value gets updated in the field outside but not on the slider. When tapped out and again tapped to show dialog the correct value of slider is displayed. How to make the slider to display the value when slided inside the Dialog Container.

```
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      width: 280,
                      child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return Dialog(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                                  elevation: 16,
                                  child: Container(
                                      height: 180.0,
                                      width: 380.0,
                                      child: Center(
                                          child: ListView(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                20, 20, 40, 10),
                                            child: Text(
                                              'Discount',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 23,
                                                  color: Color(0xFF707070)),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                            children: [
                                              ////////////////////////////////////Slider!!!!!!!
                                              Container(
                                                width: 240,
                                                child: SliderTheme(
                                                  data: SliderTheme.of(context)
                                                      .copyWith(
                                                    activeTrackColor:
                                                        Colors.red[700],
                                                    inactiveTrackColor:
                                                        Colors.red[100],
                                                    trackShape:
                                                        RoundedRectSliderTrackShape(),
                                                    trackHeight: 2.0,
                                                    thumbShape:
                                                        RoundSliderThumbShape(
                                                            enabledThumbRadius:
                                                                12.0),
                                                    thumbColor:
                                                        Colors.redAccent,
                                                    overlayColor: Colors.red
                                                        .withAlpha(32),
                                                    overlayShape:
                                                        RoundSliderOverlayShape(
                                                            overlayRadius:
                                                                28.0),
                                                    tickMarkShape:
                                                        RoundSliderTickMarkShape(),
                                                    activeTickMarkColor:
                                                        Colors.red[700],
                                                    inactiveTickMarkColor:
                                                        Colors.red[100],
                                                    valueIndicatorShape:
                                                        PaddleSliderValueIndicatorShape(),
                                                    valueIndicatorColor:
                                                        Colors.redAccent,
                                                    valueIndicatorTextStyle:
                                                        TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  child: Slider(
                                                    min: 0,
                                                    max: 20,
                                                    divisions: 80,
                                                    value: percent,
                                                    label: '$percent',
                                                    //activeColor: Color(0xFFFFAE40),
                                                    //inactiveColor: Colors.black,
                                                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                                                      setState(() {
                                                        percent = newValue;
                                                      });
                                                      Dialog();
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                  height: 30,
                                                  width: 70,
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      left: 10, right: 8),
                                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      right: 10),
                                                  color: Color(0xFF707070),
                                                  child: Row(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .spaceBetween,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Text(
                                                        '$percent',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xFFE0E0E0)),
                                                      ),
                                                      Text(
                                                        '%',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xFFE0E0E0)),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ))
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                width: 60,
                                                child: FlatButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {},
                                                  textColor: Color(0xFF707070),
                                                  child: Text('BACK'),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              FlatButton(
                                                onPressed: () {},
                                                textColor: Color(0xFFFFAE40),
                                                child: Text('ADD DISCOUNT'),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ))),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                            'Set Discount Percentage',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 22,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            ),
                            maxLines: 1,
                          )),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do `setState` within a `Dialog`, you need a [`StatefulBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html). `Dialog`s are inherently stateless and the `setState` you're currently calling is actually the `setState` of the parent widget.

You need to wrap everything that needs to be rebuilt on your `setState` call with `StatefulBuilder`. This seems to be the `Row` directly above the `Slider` as it contains all instances of the `percent` variable that needs to be updated.

```dart
...
StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {//Just wrap the Row in StatefulBuilder, everthing else can stay the same
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      ////////////////////////////////////Slider!!!!!!!
      Container(
        width: 240,
        child: SliderTheme(
          data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            activeTrackColor: Colors.red[700],
            inactiveTrackColor: Colors.red[100],
            trackShape: RoundedRectSliderTrackShape(),
            trackHeight: 2.0,
            thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
            thumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
            overlayColor: Colors.red.withAlpha(32),
            overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 28.0),
            tickMarkShape: RoundSliderTickMarkShape(),
            activeTickMarkColor: Colors.red[700],
            inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.red[100],
            valueIndicatorShape: PaddleSliderValueIndicatorShape(),
            valueIndicatorColor: Colors.redAccent,
            valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          child: Slider(
            min: 0,
            max: 20,
            divisions: 80,
            value: percent,
            label: '$percent',
            //activeColor: Color(0xFFFFAE40),
            //inactiveColor: Colors.black,
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() {
                percent = newValue;
              });
              //Dialog(); This line should be removed. It does nothing.
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 30,
        width: 70,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 8),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
        color: Color(0xFF707070),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(
              '$percent',
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFE0E0E0)),
            ),
            Text(
              '%',
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFE0E0E0)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
});
...
```

The `StateSetter` callback I created here is named `setState`, just like it would in a normal `StatefulWidget`, but this can be changed to anything if you want to distinguish between the dialog's state setter and the parent widget.

Comment: Hi @Christopher, I'm new to flutter and the code that I have written might give you heart attack :) . How can i share the whole file code with you because when I added the StatefulBuilder, it gave me errors for Color, text property and so on....

Comment: Please describe the error and share only relevant code. If you have a separate issue, ask a separate question.

Comment: I have added a ss of the code after adding the Stateuilder.

Comment: The whole file has errors ~254 errors. Can I create another Stateful class containing the dialog (wrapped inside StateBuilder) and call that where I want?

Comment: @AdamSilver You need to give a specific error. You likely forgot a parentheses or brace. These errors are not caused by `StatefulBuilder` itself, just your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for that I found the places where i missed parenthesis and comma. One more thing, at most places I have used row and column interchangeably to get things done. Is there any other way not to use so many row's and column's?

Comment: @AdamSilver That's a separate question. You should ask it in a new post. There may be a way with grid, but you would have to give specific examples in your new post.